# Locate Cells that are Occupied

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Using Excel 365 in Win 10

I am having a very small problem locating/identifying worksheet cells that are being used.  For example in cell **A1** and cell **H5** there are constants.  Cell **B2** contains the spill-able dynamic array constant:

```
={1,2,"",4,5,6;7,8,9,"",11,99;100,"",0,0,100,0}
```

[image]

Because this sheet contains both formulas and constants, I tried my trusty:

```
Sub LocateCellsWithStuffInThem()
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        Set rng = Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    End With
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

This gives:

[image]

I expected to see `B2:G4,A2,H5`.

A cell like **D2** is clearly being used.  It is part of the array constant even though `SpecialCells` does not consider it filled with either a formula or a constant and has zero length!

How can I write code to easily located occupied cells?  Do I have to loop over all the cells in `UsedRange`?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/9v7w16/dynamic_array_formulas_new_properties_in_vba/   no quick fix it looks like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop the Formula cells and add the spill area if it has it:

```
Sub LocateCellsWithStuffInThem()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each rng2 In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Cells
            If rng2.HasSpill Then
                Set rng = Union(rng2.SpillingToRange, rng)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng2, rng)
            End If
        Next rng2
    End With
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!.........................................................