# VBA Query for checking Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write the VBA Code for checking if the formula exists in a range of cells. Below is my query which is somehow not working(The cells with formulas are not turning red). Can anyone please help me out.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LResponse As Integer
    Set rr = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select a range On this worksheet", _
        Type:=8)
    If rr.HasFormula = TRUE Then
        rr.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: I tried looping too

```
Sub Test()
    Set rr = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select a range On this worksheet", _
        Type:=8)
    For Each cell In Range(rr)
        If cell.HasFormula = TRUE Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through each cell in the range. Or use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`.

Comment: `For Each cell in rr`.

Comment: Just an FYI, if one has dynamic array formulas on would need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938169/locate-cells-that-are-occupied to ensure that the spill down results get picked up.

Comment: Are you doing this to find (and check) your formulas? If so, did you know there is a shortcut for showing formula's? [Switch between displaying cell values or formulas in the worksheet. Ctrl+grave accent (`) ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Range.HasFormula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasformula) docs:

> **True** if all cells in the range contain formulas; **False** if none of the cells in the range contains a formula; **null** otherwise.

Its return value is determined by *all* the cells having or not having formulas. If only some have formulas, then it is **null**.

To fix your issue, use a loop over each individual cell:

```vb
Dim rng as Range
For Each rng in rr
    If rng.HasFormula Then
        rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT**: In your loop attempt, drop the `Range` call:

```vb
For Each cell in rr
```

**EDIT 2**: You can also use [`Range.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells):

```vb
On Error Resume Next '<~ an error will occur if there are no formula cells
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = rr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0
    
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
```